# LTE 4G simultaneous connected devices for one cell site

Tags: cellphone, 3g

I'm trying to find out **how many simultaneous connected devices can handle a typical LTE 4G or 3G public cell site**.

I know my question sounds broad, but i'am developping an mobile application which is used during a concert, and can be used by hundred to thousand of people in the same place. The application hold a web socket connection to the server, which allows devices to receive descending messages. Messages are short (less than 1,000 octets) and only sent every 2 minutes (but sent to every devices at the same time).
I've already successfully tested it with 500 devices. But I need to know what is the hypothetical limit.

Is it 1,000 devices, 10,000 devices? And where can I found elements of responses?

I was not able to find any article or website talking about this limit. Is there a limit? Or connection bandwith is always shared between the connected devices without any limit?

Thank you

**Edit:**
I am aware that in dense area, network operators "simply" reduce cell radius and deploy more base station, but the number of cells in an area is usually chosen for a "normal usage": Something like : "One people take its phone, look something for several seconds, and then close it and put it back in his pocket for 10 min". So that way, even if it's a very large crowd, the usage is not very high. 
But my scenario is different : I will ask to a crowd of 3000 people to use their phone at the same time.

Will the cell site will be able to handle it? Or will it be a massive failure because half of user will have no connection?
This is what i am trying to answer.
(Note that the web server will be powerful enough)

Comment: there's no reason a concert hall, a stadium or a mosque would only covered by a single cell; when the network gets to dense, network operators "simply" reduce cell radius and deploy more base station.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You're right, but the question is still applicable for 2 or 3 cells.

Comment: well, the point is that I'm not really sure what you're asking – an operator will always try to install enough infrastructure to serve the crowd, if they want to serve it. Basically, sure, there's physical limits, but femtocells are a thing and we can expect LTE to adapt to **very** large crowds. What is the actual problem you're expecting to have?

Comment: The number of cells in an area is usually chosen for a "normal usage": Something like : "One people take its phone, look something for several seconds, and then close it and put it back in his pocket for 10 min". So that way, even if it's a very large crowd, the usage is not very high. But my case is different : I will ask to a crowd of 3000 people to use their phone at the same time. Will the cell site will be able to handle it? Or will it be a massive failure because half of user will have no connection? (the server will be powerful enough)